# How to write sql query for show one data record from multi data record (LIKE or IN)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### **cite_name**

> 1. *London*
> 2. *Karachi*
> 3. *New York* ...

### **city_type**

> 1. *1,2,3*
> 2. *2,3*
> 3. *3,4*

how to write query to find the all cities having `city_type` like 3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not how Stack Overflow works, You come up with your problem and your tries, then community can help. Its not a place for freebies.

Comment: select * from table_name where city_type like '%3%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
select * from [your_table] where FIND_IN_SET(city_type,'3') > 0
```

**Note :** Storing more than one value in single column separated by comma is bad way to store information. Consider changing your table structure. Have a separate table for `CITY_TYPE` and map it with your table for each `CITY` in separate rows

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT* FROM [your_table] WHERE city_type LIKE '%3%'
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `LIKE` with wildcards at both end at starting as well as at the end like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE city_type LIKE '%3%';
```

Comment: i didn't copy paste the answer .take look at user post below comments @VVN